# how to load the graph in gremlin shell from cassandra

Tags: graph, titan

i am connecting to hbase and cassandra through gremlin shell and create graph but when i just stop the shell and restart the shell the graph do not persist , can anybody please tell me how to load the graph from the database to the shell back to query it .

i have tried loading the graph using following function but i get following error.

```
    gremlin> GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(g)
    No such property: GraphOfTheGodsFactory for class: groovysh_evaluate
    Display stack trace? [yN] y
    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: GraphOfTheGodsFactory fo r class: groovysh_evaluate
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptByteco deAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty( PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjec tGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:49)
    at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSi teArray.java:42)
    at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groo vy:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter$evaluate.call(Unknown Sou rce)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:152)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$0.call(Unknown Source )
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:8 8)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(I nteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl. java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java: 90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper N(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper 0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(Interacti veShellRunner.groovy:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl. java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMet hodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(P ogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(Abs tractCallSite.java:137)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57 )
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(In teractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl. java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java: 90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper N(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper 0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(Interactiv eShellRunner.groovy:66)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.(Console.java :60)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.(Console.java :67)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.main(Console.java:7 2)
```

thanks

Comment: how are you initializing the "g" variable?  can you please provide more of the code leading up to this?

Comment: g = TitanFactory.open('hbase.local')                                this is how i intialize g variable